# Format Diffrence time between two DateTime objects

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I've got a two `DateTime` objects - `StartDate` and `EndDate`
I would like format difference between two dates like `HH:mm:ss`.

```
EndTime.Subtract(StartDate).Hours + ":" +
EndTime.Subtract(StartDate).Minutes + ":" +
EndTime.Subtract(StartDate).Seconds
```

This works fine but looks ugly, I tried like this:

```
EndTime.Subtract(StartDate).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

but this threw Exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format

What I'm doing wrong?
I Would like have format like this - `01:55:23`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```
EndTime.Subtract(StartDate).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
```

Acccording to MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers do not include placeholder separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours, hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these symbols must be included in the custom format string as string literals. For example, "dd.hh:mm" defines a period (.) as the separator between days and hours, and a colon (:) as the separator between hours and minutes.

Therefore, to use ':' as the separator, you must include '\' before it.

Answer (score 1):

```
(EndTime - StartTime).ToString();
```

Subtracting a `DateTime` from a `DateTime` results in a `TimeSpan` object which provides a `.ToString()` that formats it exactly how you want. See [TimeSpan.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can also specify the format you want by providing a format which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (standard format strings) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (custom format strings).

Given that you just want hh:mm:ss, the default `.ToString()` gives you just that.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no "HH" format. Try "H" or "hh".
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#timeSeparator)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following format `"dd\\:hh\\:mm\\:ss"`

```
string str = endtime.Subtract(startime).ToString("dd\\:hh\\:mm\\:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(endTime - startTime).ToString("dd'd 'hh'h 'mm'm 'ss's'");
```

outputs a pretty readable string as follows:

> 38d 22h 58m 50s

notice that to have spaces between the parts, space has to be enclosed in single-quotes as well, e.g. `'m '`.